# Parsing different categories using Scrapy from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in Python Scrapy to parse different "model", "country" and "year" of various bikes from a webpage. There are several subcategories to track to reach the target page to scrape the required info.

The below scraper first starts from the main page then track each links within class `art-indexhmenu` then going to one layer deep it again tracks the links within class `niveau2` then again follow the links within class `niveau3` then tracking the links within class `art-indexbutton-wrapper` it reaches the target page. Then it scrapes "model", "country" and "years" of each products.

My scraper is doing its job errorlessly. However, although it is working nice, the way I've created this scraper is very repetitive to look at. As there are always room for improvement, I suppose there should be any way to make it more robust by getting rid of banality.

This is the spider (website included):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class BikePartsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'honda'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url = "https://www.bike-parts-honda.com/", callback = self.parse_links)

    def parse_links(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.art-indexhmenu a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield response.follow(link, callback = self.parse_inner_links) #going to one layer deep from landing page

    def parse_inner_links(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.niveau2 .art-indexbutton::attr(href)').extract():
            yield response.follow(link, callback = self.parse_cat_links) # digging deep to go another layer

    def parse_cat_links(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.niveau3 .art-indexbutton::attr(href)').extract():
            yield response.follow(link, callback = self.parse_target_links) ## go inside another layer

    def parse_target_links(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.art-indexbutton-wrapper .art-indexbutton::attr(href)').extract():
            yield response.follow(link, callback = self.parse_docs) # tracking links leading to the target page

    def parse_docs(self, response):
        items = [item for item in response.css('.titre_12_red::text').extract()]
        yield {"categories":items} #this is where the scraper parses the info

c = CrawlerProcess({               #using CrawlerProcess() method to be able to run from the IDE
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',   
})
c.crawl(BikePartsSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: "My scraper is doing it's job errorlessly." In how much time, usually? And what's the expected output?

Comment: Do you pipe the output into something useful with a secondary program by chance?

Comment: In case of output, the `categories` defined within my scraper is enough @Mast. I'm not worried about output. The thing is I wish to know any better way other than what i did above cause it looks so repetitive.

Comment: But you don't appear to do anything with those categories. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, right you are. I can see the results in the IDE and I checked whether the output I'm having is accurate. Btw, why the output is so important here as I've stated in the first place that i would like to go for any better design. Thanks.

Comment: You could make it less repetitive, but not by much and I'm not sure it's worth the risk. Since the target site is quite massive, validating the new code against the old simply takes too long.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Mast for your kind words. I'm very new to scrapy so I wasn't so sure. i do have some posts concerning scrapy here, though.

Answer (score 1):

> this scraper is very repetitive

Yeah, I get that motivation.
I'm glad that's a thing you're worried about.

Offhand? No, I don't see any obvious improvements to the code.

But I will observe that
[bs4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4)
offers recursive methods such as
[find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc).

There's more than four levels of "let's parse at one level deeper"
in this codebase. I suspect that recursing down, in a single function
call, would go a long way toward tightening up the source code.